# Wordpress tags that begin with "cif-series" and list those post titles with link

Tags: wordpress, tags, posts

I'm looking for a way to ...

List all Wordpress tags that begin with "cif-series" (make them clickable to posts that match tag)
List all Wordpress posts associated with tags that begin with "cif-series" (title with link)

Is this possible? I have a way to manually select multiple tags, but this will continue to grow thus the "begins with" portion is what could save me time ongoing.

Thanks for your help! Anyone?